# Включение/Отключение proxy_protocol в зависимости от конкретного домена

Tags: nginx

Ищу способ, включать/отключать директиву proxy_protocol в зависимости от конкретного хоста. if, в stream не работает.

```
stream {

    upstream server3 {
        server 192.168.44.12:443;
    }
    upstream server2 {
        server 192.168.44.11:443;
    }
    upstream server1 {
        server 192.168.44.10:443;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
        hostnames;
        .srv3.site.com server3; // должен быть proxy_protocol off;
        .srv2.site.com server2; // должен быть proxy_protocol on;
        .srv1.site.com server1; // должен быть proxy_protocol on;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;

        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $upstream;

        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно попробовать нагородить два server-блока

Comment: @AlexeyTen Обязательное условие для данной конфигурации - один 443 порт, в случае с двумя server порт будет разный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать что-то такое:

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
    hostnames;
    .srv3.site.com 127.0.0.1:4443; // должен быть proxy_protocol off;
    .srv2.site.com server2; // должен быть proxy_protocol on;
    .srv1.site.com server1; // должен быть proxy_protocol on;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl_preread on;
    proxy_pass $upstream;

    proxy_protocol on;
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:4443 proxy_protocol;
    proxy_pass server3;
    proxy_protocol off;
}
```

Comment: Это действительно работает, но при такой схеме взаимодействия на каждый домен с выключенным proxy_protocol нужно будет создавать свой блок server. Т.к выбрать домен с помощью $upstream уже не выйдет.

Comment: Ну кажется можно сделать `$upstream2` для них

Comment: Да, можно. Но я в итоге переписал конфиг, взяв за основу Ваш ответ. Удалив блоки upstream и начал с каждым доменом добавлять новый блок server со своим портом, адрес которых записываем в map. У каждого блока server свое значение proxy_protocol(on/off), собственно задача решена. Благодарю.